# Tamaño input text HTML

Tags: html, text

Si la nomenclatura para escribir un input de type text es la siguiente:

```
<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="30" value="Nombre" name="nombre">
```

**Deseo que el tamaño de la caja, en cuanto a largo-ancho, sea el equivalente al tamaño del dato que obtengo de una consulta.**
Es decir, que si tengo como nombre: Pepe, no me muestre un size="40" por defecto, y sí, un tamaño size="6" que sería el más apropiado.

¿Esto se puede realizar o solamente se puede definir la propiedad de antemano?

**Código ejemplo:**

```
<label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" size="6" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $objeto->getNombre(); ?> "/>
```

Ingreso en la caja de texto el nombre, extraido de una consulta SQL, y le añado tamaño 6 por defecto, ¿puedo añadir un tamaño idóneo con el dato obtenido?
En mi caso el nombre es: Pepe, ¿pero y si fuera: María Luisa Dolores?

Comment: El tema de limitar el número de caracteres de un textbox no tiene nada que ver con la memoria ni el tamaño que va a ocupar la página. Es, por decirlo de alguna manera, una forma de validar que un dato no exceda de un tamaño máximo si lo vas a insertar en BBDD.

Comment: No hablo del tamaño maxlength, hablo del tamaño de la caja de texto. No tiene nada que ver con la memoria. Es a forma visual que sea más legible.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta, realmente? El atributo size indica el número de caracteres visibles, por lo que sí puedes ajustar el tamaño al valor inicial del campo si lo consideras oportuno. Si lo que quieres es que crezca o disminuya según el usuario escribe, necesitarás javascript.

Comment: Quiero que crezca o disminuya según el dato que se obtiene en la consulta, lo extraigo, como muestro en el ejemplo, de la siguiente manera: echo $objeto->getNombre();

Comment: pues usa la longitud de ese string como valor para size... sigo tener claro qué respuesta buscas

Comment: La respuesta que busco es "Usa la longitud de ese string como valor para el size". ¿Un ejemplo? Por ejemplo utilizando: strlen($objeto->getNombre(); ¿Cómo integro ese valor X al size? ¿Mediante Javascript o puedo hacerlo directamente con PHP dentro del size="<?php $longitud ?>"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coge la longitud del string en php:

```
$longitud = strlen($objeto->getNombre())
```

Y pónle la variable como valor del size:

```
<label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud; ?>" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $objeto->getNombre(); ?> "/>
```